# netbeans IDE GIt Command Failed

Tags: git, netbeans

If I try and do any command under Team -> Git I get the following error

> Java.io.IOException: User config file /home/user/.gitconfig invalid org.eclipse.jgit.errors.ConfigInvalidException: Cannot read file 
>   /home/user/.gitconfig

the file is there, has my github username and email that's it and I made the permissions 777

I'm using netbeans 8.0 and the excellent ubuntu 14.0.1 desktop
Anyone know how to solve it please.

.gitconfig contents is

```
           name=Gav
           email=my@email.com




         [user]
            email = my@email.com
            name = Gav
```

Comment: Can you paste the contents of `/home/user/.gitconfig` in your question?

Comment: sorry I just realised I'm a dumb ass and somehow those 2 top lines got in there somehow, thought it was  strange but didn't question the logic, then seen the correct way is just > [user]
            email = my@email.com
            name = Gav

Comment: @GAV I have edited my answer with the right content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the exact content of the .gitconfig:

- either it contains some unknown option or typo (as in [this thread](http://forums.netbeans.org/post-151396.html#151396)),
- or, as in this [Netbeans issue](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=218793), it isn't saved in the right format (for instance, [UTF-8 with BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) instead of the normal UTF-8 without BOM).

---

In the OP's case, the first two lines are incorrect.
It should be only:

```
     [user]
        email = my@email.com
        name = Gav
```